# buttons taking up same amount of space in android

Tags: android

there has been a few similar question on this topic and i've tried alot of them by now but they don't work.
i have three buttons and i want them to take up the same amount of space on the top of the screen. i've tried putting them in in linear layout and using the weights but they don't apear on the graphical layout at all. any suggestions

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".FragActivity" >

        <LinearLayout         
            android:layout_width="match_parent"         
            android:layout_height="0dp"         
            android:orientation="horizontal"         
            android:weightSum="1"         
            android:layout_gravity="top">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"  
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="home"
                android:text="Home" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Friends" 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
                android:onClick="Friends"
                android:text="Friends" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/makeEvent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"  
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
                android:onClick="makeEvent"
                android:text="Make Event" />

         </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your LinearLayout will never show up: `android:layout_height="0dp"`. Also its weightSum is wrong - should be 1.5 (0.5 * 3) - but you can simply remove it (Android manages the sum by itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout         
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:orientation="horizontal"         
        android:weightSum="3"         
        android:layout_gravity="top">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:text="Home" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Friends" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:onClick="Friends"
            android:text="Friends" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makeEvent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:onClick="makeEvent"
            android:text="Make Event" />

     </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

all fixed. your in a linearlayout bud, and you dont set widths and heights, to zero. you have three buttons so set weight sum to 3, and give each button a weight of 1. remove the placement tags, as in a linear layout they will be placed in a linear style.

replace your code with mine and give it a shot

Comment: This should work also, just a note...if they are all going to take up equal space then `weight_sum` isn't needed and the `weight`s aren't important as long as they are the same. Also, `width` should be "0dp" in a horizontal `layout` using `weights`

Comment: true, but if you dont center the buttons in the linearlayout without weight you might have issues, in scaling from one screen to another. he has gravity set to top, so if its on a phone those buttons might take up a whole top, while on a tablet the buttons will only take up the same space on the side of the screen. might want to change his gravity to keep consistancy

Comment: I don't understand this, "if you dont center the buttons in the linearlayout without weight". And, no, if they take up the same amount of space then their shouldn't be scaling issues

Comment: the button wont scale, but the screen will. a 100 dp button looks the same on the phone as on a tablet, if my phone is 320dp wide i have 20dp of deadspace, if my tablet is 680dp wide i have 380 dp of deadspace.  since either way my buttons only take up 300dp several ways around it, i was just making a suggestion about the gravity to enhance the layout on all screens

Answer (score 1):

You've got the `height` and `width` backwards for a horizontal `layout. Switch your`LinearLayout to

```
<LinearLayout         
        android:layout_width="0dp"         
        android:layout_height="match_parent"         
        android:orientation="horizontal"         
        android:layout_gravity="top">
```

otherwise your height is 0 so of course you won't see anything.

I also removed `weight_sum` because it isn't needed in this case so it's safer just to let the device calculate for you.

You can also remove `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"` from your `Button` because that property doesn't exist for `LinearLayout` which is what your `Button` is wrapped in.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:weightSum="3"` to the `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to every `Button` as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FragActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="home"
            android:text="Home" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Friends"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="Friends"
            android:text="Friends" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makeEvent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="makeEvent"
            android:text="Make Event" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```